# Is ??? a valid symbol or operator in scala

Tags: scala

I have seen the symbol

```
???
```

used in scala code, i however don't know if it's meant to be pseudo code or actual scala code, but my eclipse IDE for scala doesn't flag it and the eclipse worksheet actually evaluates it.
I haven't been able to find anything via google search.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is a valid identifier.

Since Scala 2.10, there is a `???` method in [Predef](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef%24) which simply throws a `NotImplementedError`.

```
def ??? : Nothing = throw new NotImplementedError
```

This is intended to be used for quickly sketching the skeleton of some code, leaving the implementations of methods for later, for example:

```
class Foo[A](a: A) {

  def flatMap[B](f: A => Foo[B]): Foo[B] = ???

}
```

Because it has a type of `Nothing` (which is a subtype of every other type), it will type-check in place of any value, allowing you to compile the incomplete code without errors. It's often seen in exercises, where the solution needs to be written in place of `???`.

Comment: Interestingly, it was introduced into the standard library fairly soon after the first Coursera Scala course term, where it was included in the exercise library. Hardly a coincidence, probably ;).

Answer (score 1):

To search for method names that are ASCII or unicode strings:

---

SO search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[scala]+%22%3F%3F%3F%22

finds this thread [Scala and Python's pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763543/scala-and-pythons-pass/13763641#13763641)

---

scalex covers scala 2.9.1 and scalaz 6.0 http://scalex.org/?q=%3C%3A%3C